# How to include multiple objects of the same type in SOAP Response using PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm using PHP's SoapServer and I want the response to include multiple items of the same type. My wsdl for this section looks like this.

```
<xsd:element name="getSalesTaxResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="totalTaxAmount" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="productTax" type="tns:getSalesTaxResultInformation" />
          </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="getSalesTaxResultInformation">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>This object stores information related to product tax request
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="productId" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="productNRCPrice" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="taxAmount" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

In PHP my brain is stuck and I can't for the life of me figure out how to include multiple "productTax" records in the response. I'm currently doing this, but it doesn't do what I want.

```
        $this->response = new GetSalesTaxResponse();
        $this->response->totalTaxAmount = '21.93';
        $this->response->productTax = array(
            (object) array(
                'productId'=>'3123',
                'productNRCPrice'=>'201.20',
                'taxAmount'=>'10.10'),
            (object) array('productId'=>'2103',
                'productNRCPrice'=>'102.10',
                'taxAmount'=>'11.83')
        );
        file_put_contents('/tmp/burp', print_r($this->response, TRUE), FILE_APPEND);
        return $this->response->getSoapVar();
```

But in SOAP-UI, I see this.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/SOAP/Billing">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getSalesTaxResponse>
         <totalTaxAmount>21.93</totalTaxAmount>
         <productTax>
            <SOAP-ENC:Struct>
               <productId>3123</productId>
               <productNRCPrice>201.20</productNRCPrice>
               <taxAmount>10.10</taxAmount>
            </SOAP-ENC:Struct>
            <SOAP-ENC:Struct>
               <productId>2103</productId>
               <productNRCPrice>102.10</productNRCPrice>
               <taxAmount>11.83</taxAmount>
            </SOAP-ENC:Struct>
         </productTax>
      </ns1:getSalesTaxResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**That makes sense based on what I'm doing in PHP, but how do I build the response in PHP to look like this instead?**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/SOAP/Billing">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns1:getSalesTaxResponse>
             <totalTaxAmount>21.93</totalTaxAmount>
             <productTax>
                   <productId>3123</productId>
                   <productNRCPrice>201.20</productNRCPrice>
                   <taxAmount>10.10</taxAmount>
              </productTax>
              <productTax>
                   <productId>2103</productId>
                   <productNRCPrice>102.10</productNRCPrice>
                   <taxAmount>11.83</taxAmount>
             </productTax>
          </ns1:getSalesTaxResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a complex type array from within PHP, you must create a new complex type which your  `getSalesTaxResponse` uses, and has a sequence of elements with the array type of `getSalesTaxResultInformation`:

```
<complexType name="getSalesTaxResultInformation_Array">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
      <sequence>
        <element name="productTax" type="tns:getSalesTaxResultInformation"
                 maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </sequence>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Which makes your `getSalesTaxResponse` as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="getSalesTaxResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="totalTaxAmount" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="productTax" type="tns:getSalesTaxResultInformation_Array" />
          </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This gives SoapServer enough information to work out what type your array data is, essentially a map

If SoapServer doesn't find the right array element type, you'll have to cast each `productTax` row to `getSalesTaxResultInformation` yourself:

```
$array_element = new SoapVar($response_array, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'getSalesTaxResultInformation');
```

Comment: This appears to be working, but I'm getting a validation error. src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'soapenc:Array.' It was detected that 'soapenc:Array' is in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document. I added this to definitions: xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"